# Hello, could you help me debug the following python tkinter GUI code?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

so sorry to post this really basic question. But trust me I tried a while but couldnot make it work.. 
I am trying to achieve the following goal:
Step 1. create a tkinter window that has an entry field and a button
Step 2. when the button is pressed a new window will open which will also have an entry field and a button

I have succesfully done step 1, and it works..  however i am having problem in the second step.. when i press the button on the first window, a new window opens with a entry field but the button is not displayed .. i dont understand why.. could you guys help??
I get the error : `bad window path name ".!button2"`
and this is the GUI that pops up: [gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Osd.png)

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()
root.title("URL Checker")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def urlchecker():  

    url = entry1.get() 
    predictions_LR = "Not malicious"
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= predictions_LR)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)

    root2= tk.Tk()
    root2.title("News Checker")

    canvas2 = tk.Canvas(root2, width = 400, height = 300)
    canvas2.pack()

    entry2 = tk.Entry (root2) 
    canvas2.create_window(200, 140, window=entry2)

    def newschecker():

        title = entry2.get()
        title = title.lower()

        label2 = tk.Label(root2, text= "The news is real!!!!")
        canvas2.create_window(200, 230, window=label2)

    button2 = tk.Button(text='Check article', command=newschecker)
    canvas2.create_window(200, 180, window=button2)

    root2.mainloop()



button1 = tk.Button(text='Check URL', command=urlchecker)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify master for your second button

```
button2 = tk.Button(master=root2,text='Check article', command=newschecker)
canvas2.create_window(200, 180, window=button2)
```

Comment: It worked..thank you brother.. could you explain to me why button1 didnt required "master = root"

Comment: When there is one window active it is obviously the root. However when you create the second window the parent window of the button should be specified (will it be drawn in the first window you created, or the second?). You should also consider using tk.Toplevel() instead of tk.Tk() if you want to create many windows as there should be only one main window(root)

Comment: Ok brother, thank you for your explanation it would help me a lot